# Excel refresh all flow, execute pivot refresh 1st before function

Tags: excel, function, pivot-table

is there a way to refresh a xlsx file, so no macro, that execute a query function (determines the source based on a cell) to execute 1st before refreshing the pivot?

Comment: Can you please give more details about what you mean by "refresh xlsx file"? Update formulas? Update certain pivot table? Update certain macro?. The macro that you don't want to be affected, is it located as an vba Event - "Events are actions performed by users which trigger Excel VBA to execute code."

Comment: I mean, I have an xlsx file that also have a power query function. the problem is that it executes the pivot refresh before the Query function